# multiple iFrames not showing in FF, Chrome and Safari

Tags: iframe

I know using iFrame is strongly discouraged but I need to make the application that runs on IE8 and older and they already have large old codes using iFrames. I was stuck in a problem about the iFrames. Here is my two iframes:

```
<div>
 <div width="20%" height="100%">
  <iframe width="20%" name="treestruct" src="menu.html" height="800px"/>
 </div>
 <div  width="70%" height="100%">
  <iframe width="80%" name="mainbody" src="content.html" height="800px"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Recently, I have been asked to make it work for Firefox too. But when I tried to see it on FF, the only first iFrame is shown. It works fine in IE but not in FF or any other modern browsers. I really got stuck what's going on here. What will be the solution for this? I know this might be a minor problem and I am also a great supporter of HTML5 and want to avoid these types of deprecated tags, but I have large code written in old html and have to make them work on IE8 and older. I do not have options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to w3school, you have to close your iframe tag with `</iframe>`. So change your code to something like this:

```
<div>
 <div width="20%" height="100%">
  <iframe width="20%" name="treestruct" src="menu.html" height="800px"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div  width="70%" height="100%">
  <iframe width="80%" name="mainbody" src="content.html" height="800px"></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

and give it a try. It should work just fine...

Comment: EhasnT, thanks. I don't know how I forgot this minor things :-)

Comment: Thanks, same case with me & it took around 3 hours to figure out such small thing.